# Recursive concat xml path and values

Tags: python, recursion, xpath, lxml

currently I am trying to concate a xml path (with sub-levels). Based on this path I want to parse throug the elements of given path.

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<File>
    <Root>
        <Group>
            <Name>Data</Name>
            <Entry>
                <String>
                    <Key>Name</Key>
                    <Value>Michael</Value>
                </String>
            </Entry>
            <Group>
                <Name>SUB</Name>
                <Entry>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Name</Key>
                        <Value>Vanessa</Value>
                    </String>
                </Entry>
                <Group>
                    <Name>SUB_SUB</Name>
                    <Entry>
                        <String>
                            <Key>Name</Key>
                            <Value>Ernie</Value>
                        </String>
                    </Entry>
                    <Group>
                        <Name>SUB_SUB_SUB</Name>
                        <Entry>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Name</Key>
                                <Value>Paul</Value>
                            </String>
                        </Entry>
                    </Group>
                </Group>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <Name>SUB2</Name>
                <Entry>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Name</Key>
                        <Value>Peter</Value>
                    </String>
                </Entry>
                <Group>
                    <Name>SUB_SUB2</Name>
                    <Entry>
                        <String>
                            <Key>Name</Key>
                            <Value>Klaus</Value>
                        </String>
                    </Entry>
                </Group>
            </Group>
        </Group>
        
    </Root>
</File>
```

Output should be (EDITED-> added subfolder)

```
File\Root\Data Name=Michael
File\Root\Data\SUB Name=Vanessa
File\Root\Data\SUB_SUB Name=Ernie
File\Root\Data\SUB_SUB\SUB_SUB_SUB Name=Paul
File\Root\Data\SUB2 Name=Peter
File\Root\Data\SUB2\SUB_SUB2 Name=Klaus
```

Since I am new to python I have only managed to write the path of the elements or the text of a specific element.

I think I need a recursive function to concatenate the Name of each group and check if the group has further children named "Group"

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

As soon as the iteration reaches the element "Group" I need to select the node "Name" of that Group (Data, Sub, Sub_Sub, ...)
Within this node (File\Root\Group)  I want to select the elements Entry and write out their children + content

So it's

```
File\Root\[Groupname]\              Name=Michael
(File\Root\Data\                    Name=Michael)
File\Root\[Groupname]\[Groupname]   Name=Vanessa
(File\Root\Data\SUB\                Name=Vanessa)
```

Hopefully this helps

EDIT2: (see above -> added subfolders to expected output)
I just played around with getpath, list(elem), for each loops, elem.tag / elem.text, find, findall(.//Group) etc. but unfortunately I am not able to select the correct nodes and address further elements and subelement. So my code wont help here

Comment: What kind of "path" is that, at what point do you use the element names (e.g. `File` or `Root`), at what point the `Data` or `Sub` element contents?

Comment: It would help to see the code you've written so far.

Comment: In your example output, why isn't `File\Root\Data\SUB_SUB_SUB` actually `File\Root\Data\SUB\SUB_SUB\SUB_SUB_SUB`? How do you know which group names to elide and which to keep?

Comment: thanks for your remarks, I have added some information!